# Finding a limit before solving an differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Part of a book I'm studying has left me solving a particular limit as an exercise and would like some help in doing so. I've been given:
$$\frac{du}{dt}=au^\frac{2}{3}-bu$$ with $u(0)=u_0$ solving this differential equation wasn't too hard all it took was substituting in $v=u^\frac{1}{3}$ and solving the subsequent equation to eventually find $u(t)=\frac{1}{b^3}(a-(a-bu_0^\frac{1}{3})e^{-\frac{bt}{3}})^3$. However an exercise that was left was to find: $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}u(t)$$ without solving the differential equation, how do I go about finding this?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $u(t)$ approaches a constant at large times (otherwise, the limit of $u(t)$ as $t$ approaches $\infty$ does not exist.) Then, at large times, $du/dt = 0$. Can you take it from here?

As a check, your result should match what you expect from the exact solution you obtained for $u(t)$.

If you want to understand why $u(t)$ must approach a constant at large times, think about direction fields.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the exact behaviour depends on $a$ and $b$. For example if $a=0$ and $b<0$ then $u(t)\rightarrow \infty$ (if $u_0$ is sufficiently large, with sign dependent on $u_0$). However this answer does give the possible values for the limit in the case that it exists and is finite (and I suspect that $b>0$ is a sufficient condition for that).

Comment: @dan What if $u$ does not approach a constant?  Suppose that $u$ oscillates indefinitely, or suppose $u$ unbounded, as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: @MarkViola As mentioned in my comment there are cases where $u\rightarrow \infty$, but if $b>0$ this cannot happen. Regarding oscillation, because this is a first order (real) ODE it cannot display oscilatory behaviour. As the answer mentions this can be seen by looking at direction fields.

Comment: To clarify I should have said first order real autonomous ODE.

Comment: @Fishbane My comment was directed explicitly to "dan." That said, you would need to prove or reference your assertions (e.g., a first-order autonomous ODE cannot admit solutions that oscillate, and if $b>0$, then $u$ must be bounded).

Comment: @MarkViola I am aware that you directed your comment to "dan", however given that this is a Q&A website and I felt I could adress your concern, I felt it made sense for me to answer. Regarding my assertions, given that I am not doing homework nor writing a paper I feel that citing the results I am using would be a bit odd, particularly given that most courses on ODE's would cover this. However a quick explaination is that if you draw arrows on $\Bbb{R}$ showing which direction $u$ moves if it has any particular value then you can see that it cannot reach any point twice...

Comment: (The exact reason for being unable to reach any point twice is that you would have to travel opposite to the drection you travelled in the first time you were at that point to get back) Regarding boundedness, just consider the sign of $\frac{du}{dt}$ for large values of $u$, if $b>0$ then the sign is always directed towards $0$ for large enough $u$ so we cannot possibly grow without bound.

Comment: @Fishbane I understand all of this.  The OP might not.  That is my point.  The OP is seeking an explanation of how one can deduce properties of an ODE without having solved the ODE.  And now you might understand better the reason for my addressing dan and the solution that dan posted.

Comment: @MarkViola Sure, and if the OP has a problem they can ask, and dan need not be the one to answer. His answer covers the main ideas and my comment adresses an edge case. The further comments now give some more detail, but explaining everything just in case the OP doesn't know seems silly to me as if they are confused they can ask in a comment.

Comment: @Fishbane Again, I directed my comment to "dan" because I believe that this post does not provide useful guidance to address the OP's question "... without solving the differential equation, how do I go about finding this?" That is all.